# How to save the file received as response to powershell web request within an Azure function app to an Azure storage container?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I have an Azure function app that makes the following web request:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $body -SkipCertificateCheck`

On my local machine, I can save the returned `XML` file as `OutFile` to local disk. However, in the actual environment this is on an Azure function app and therefore I don't think that I can save the file to disk. Instead, I want to redirect it to a storage container in Azure.

I have tried Azure function output bindings in order to redirect the response there but failed to write the actual file:

`Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $response.content`

All this write to the storage container is a string value. So how do I write the actual file received as a response to `InvokeRestMethod` within the Azure function app to the Azure storage container in this environment?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the file is huge, you can indeed save it to the local file system, even when running on Azure. Just select the proper location and don't forget to clean up:

```
$f = New-TemporaryFile
try {
    Invoke-RestMethod ... -OutFile $f.FullName
    # Do whatever you want with this file
    ...
} finally {
    Remove-Item $f.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read your file into byte array and pass it as argument.

```bsh
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

New-Item -Path 'test.txt' -ItemType File
Set-Content 'test.txt' 'Welcome to www.thecodemanual.pl'
$file = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('test.txt')

Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $file

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

and then you will get:

[image]